# Error with zip_open from libzip

Tags: c++, zip, zlib, unzip

I am learning C++, and I decided to make a little program that zip/unzip files to train me.
I downloaded [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html) and zlib and linked them to my compiler (MinGW with Code::Blocks on Windows). So I tried to open my zip file with zip_open() and got an error :

> undefined reference to `_imp__zip_open`

Here is the code:

```
#include <zip.h>
#include <zlib.h>

int main()
{
    int error(0);
    zip *foo = zip_open("foo.zip", 0, &error);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know where this is coming from and I would really like some help, because I don't find anything on Google (surely cause the problem is simple).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may try linking libzip (-lzip) on your build command line.

Comment: You're right, man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't linked to libzip. Make sure you are infact linking to it, and that the path to the lib is in your link path.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the discussion on [this thread](http://www.nih.at/listarchive/libzip-discuss/msg00304.html) from the libzip-discuss list it looks like you are trying to link against a static version of libzip but with the preprocessor symbol `ZLIB_DLL` defined. You should only have `ZLIB_DLL` defined if linking against the dll version.